# How to get slider images on fancybox popup, how to work on this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a question on my project,
currently i am using tn gallery slider. In that slider i have one link when i click that link those slider images have to display in fancy box popup.
can any one help with coding?
I am new to jquery and javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Thumbnailer.config.shaderOpacity = 1;
    var tn1 = $('.mygallery').tn3({
        skinDir:"img",
        imageClick:"fullscreen",
        image:{
        maxZoom:1.5,
        crop:true,
        clickEvent:"dblclick",
        transitions:[{
        type:"blinds"
        },{
        type:"grid"
        },{
        type:"grid",
        duration:460,
        easing:"easeInQuad",
        gridX:1,
        gridY:8,
        // flat, diagonal, circle, random
        sort:"random",
        sortReverse:false,
        diagonalStart:"bl",
        // fade, scale
        method:"scale",
        partDuration:360,
        partEasing:"easeOutSine",
        partDirection:"left"
        }]
        }
    });
$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox(
     {
            'transitionIn'  : 'none',
            'transitionOut' : 'none',
            'titlePosition' : 'over',
            'titleFormat'   : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
                return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
      }
        });
   });
```

HTML code:

```
     <div class="mygallery">
    <div class="tn3 album">     
 <ol>
    <li>
        <h4>Hohensalzburg Castle</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Salzburg, Austria</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/1.jpg">
            <img src="img/35x35/1.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Isolated sandy cove</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Zakynthos island, Greece</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/2.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/2.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>A view from the Old Town</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Herceg Novi, Montenegro</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/3.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/3.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Walls of the Old Town</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Kotor, Montenegro</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/4.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/4.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Boat in the port</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Sousse, Tunis</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/5.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/5.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Wall of the Jain temple</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Jaisalmer, India</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/6.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/6.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>City park</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Negotin, Serbia</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/7.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/7.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Taj Mahal mausoleum</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Agra, India</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/8.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/8.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Zante Port</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Zakynthos, Greece</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/9.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/9.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Rustovo Monastery</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Budva, Montenegro</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/10.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/10.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>The Mezquita, Cathedral and former Great Mosque</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Cordoba, Spain</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/11.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/11.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Wine Cellars</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Rajac, Serbia</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/12.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/12.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Zante Port</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Zakynthos, Greece</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/9.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/9.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Rustovo Monastery</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Budva, Montenegro</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/10.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/10.jpg" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>The Mezquita, Cathedral and former Great Mosque</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Cordoba, Spain</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/11.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/11.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Wine Cellars</h4>
        <div class="tn3 description">Rajac, Serbia</div>
        <a href="img/620x378/12.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/12.jpg"/>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ol>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You need to post some code! Better yet, code and a jsfiddle.

Comment: Can u get my code. did u understand my qustion brother ??

Comment: You do not have fancybox in your code.

Comment: I have basic code to get fancy box, But my doubt was how to get those slider images on fancy box. can you understand???? sorry for my bad englis. please help me

Comment: You should add your fancybox code so you can get the help you want.

Comment: I have edit that code on above. did you get it ???

Comment: A link to your project would be helpful but for fancybox to work, you need to add `rel="example_group"` to your links like this `<a rel="example_group" href="img/620x378/12.jpg"><img src="img/35x35/12.jpg"/></a>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your HTML should look like with your fancybox code. Since I can not see your site, I have no idea if you are loading javascript and css files correctly, or what versions of these files you are using etc.

```
<div class="mygallery">
<div class="tn3 album">     
<ol>
<li>
    <h4>Hohensalzburg Castle</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Salzburg, Austria</div>
    <a href="img/620x378/1.jpg">
        <img src="img/35x35/1.jpg"/>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>Isolated sandy cove</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Zakynthos island, Greece</div>
    <a rel="example_group" href="img/620x378/2.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/2.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>A view from the Old Town</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Herceg Novi, Montenegro</div>
    <a href="img/620x378/3.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/3.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>Walls of the Old Town</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Kotor, Montenegro</div>
    <a rel="example_group" href="img/620x378/4.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/4.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>Boat in the port</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Sousse, Tunis</div>
    <a href="img/620x378/5.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/5.jpg"/>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <h4>Wall of the Jain temple</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Jaisalmer, India</div>
    <a href="img/620x378/6.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/6.jpg" />
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <h4>City park</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Negotin, Serbia</div>
    <a href="img/620x378/7.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/7.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>Taj Mahal mausoleum</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Agra, India</div>
    <a rel="example_group" href="img/620x378/8.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/8.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>Zante Port</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Zakynthos, Greece</div>
    <a href="img/620x378/9.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/9.jpg"/>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>Rustovo Monastery</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Budva, Montenegro</div>
    <a href="img/620x378/10.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/10.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>The Mezquita, Cathedral and former Great Mosque</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Cordoba, Spain</div>
    <a rel="example_group" href="img/620x378/11.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/11.jpg" />
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <h4>Wine Cellars</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Rajac, Serbia</div>
    <a href="img/620x378/12.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/12.jpg"/>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>Zante Port</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Zakynthos, Greece</div>
    <a href="img/620x378/9.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/9.jpg"/>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>Rustovo Monastery</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Budva, Montenegro</div>
    <a rel="example_group" href="img/620x378/10.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/10.jpg" />
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <h4>The Mezquita, Cathedral and former Great Mosque</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Cordoba, Spain</div>
    <a href="img/620x378/11.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/11.jpg"/>
    </a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <h4>Wine Cellars</h4>
    <div class="tn3 description">Rajac, Serbia</div>
    <a rel="example_group" href="img/620x378/12.jpg">
    <img src="img/35x35/12.jpg"/>
    </a>
</li>
</ol>
</div>
</div>
```